# How did we calculate $\mathbb{E}\left(X_1\right)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X=\left(X_1, X_2, X_3\right)$ be $N(\mu, \Sigma)$-distributed where $\mu=c(0,1,2)$ and
$$
\Sigma=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 2 \\
-1 & 3 & -6 \\
2 & -6 & 15
\end{array}\right)
$$
Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and define
$$
\begin{aligned}
& Y_1:=X_1 \\
& Y_2:=X_2-a X_1 \\
& Y_3:=X_3-b X_2-c X_1
\end{aligned}
$$
(a)Find
$$
\mathrm{E}\left(\left(X_1-X_2\right)^2\right)
$$

---

Answer:
(a) We have
$$
\mathrm{E}\left(\left(X_1-X_2\right)^2\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(X_1^2\right)-2 \mathrm{E}\left(X_1 X_2\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X_2^2\right) .
$$
Since
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{E}\left(X_1^2\right) & =\mathbb{V}\left(X_1\right)+\mathrm{E}\left(X_1\right)^2=\Sigma_{1,1}+0 \cdot 0=1, \\
\mathrm{E}\left(X_1 X_2\right) & =\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_1, X_2\right)+\mathrm{E}\left(X_1\right) \mathbb{E}\left(X_2\right)=\Sigma_{1,2}+0 \cdot 1=-1, \\
\mathrm{E}\left(X_2^2\right) & =\mathbb{V}\left(X_2\right)+\mathrm{E}\left(X_2\right)^2=3+1^2=4,
\end{aligned}
$$
we find that
$$
\mathrm{E}\left(\left(X_1-X_2\right)^2\right)=1-2-(-1)+4=7
$$

---

My question is how did we calculate $\mathbb{E}\left(X_1\right)$ in the above solution? How is $\mathbb{E}\left(X_1\right) = 0$ and how is $\mathbb{E}\left(X_2\right) = 1$?

Comment: The expectation of $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is given in the problem i.e. $\mu = c(0, 1, 2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to calculate. You specified that $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ has mean vector $\mu=(0,1,2)$, so $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=\mu_1=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_2]=\mu_2=1$. (I assume that the "$c$" in front of your statement of $\mu$ is a typo, since you only define $c$ after that very same statement.)